# Take ownership of a file that used to be owned by a domain account

Tags: windows-7, active-directory, permissions

I upgraded a PC to Windows 7 (Ultimate x64) from Vista when it was part of a domain.

I later removed it from the domain.

I now cannot take ownership as an Administrator user of a certain file on my system harddrive.

Through properties | security | advanced | owner dialog box it says "Unable to display current owner" and when I click "Edit" and I try to set it to the Administrators group or a specific user in that group it brings up a dialog that says "Unable to set new owner on [file].  Access is denied"

When I run the cmd as administrator and similarly try "takeown" I get "INFO: Access is denied."

I do not have access to the domain server but do have access to the username and password that it probably thinks owns it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yep as a local admin you can always take ownership of any local file.  This sort of problem is usually a corrupt or readonly drive. (as you found)

Answer (score 1):

Nevermind, a boot-time chkdsk fixed the problem.